Pressure gauge on flow test pipe reading zero, why?
I'm trying to determine the cv values for water of a collection of 90-degree 4-inch elbow valves, and one of the things I need to determine this for a particular flow rate is the input and output pressure, but I'm having difficulty measuring the output pressure.
My setup: a 500-gallon pressurized tank, with the inlet flange of the elbow mounted to an opening in the bottom of the tank. I can set and accurately measure the input water pressure up to 100 psi. To read output pressure, I mounted a 2-foot pipe to the outlet flange (pointed horizontally) and drilled a NPT hole in the middle of the pipe (1 foot from each side) for a pressure transducer to read the output pressure.
My problem: The pressure gauge is reading zero, except for burst pressure upon closing the inlet. I have tried up to 25 psi and several transducers, analog/digital gauges, I'm stumped. My department is stumped. I don't understand why the gauge is reading no pressure when there's clearly water pressure. I've tried orienting the gauge in different directions (up, down, or sideways, relative to the ground) and nothing seems to make a difference.

are you sure there's a hole into the process?  If you take the gauge off does water come out?

"The pressure gauge is reading zero, except for burst pressure upon closing the inlet." Should that be "outlet"? In any case, if you close the outlet do you get the same pressure as that in the tank? (You should.) I'm an electrical engineer so this isn't my specialty, but what pressure drop are you expecting on the elbow and what would you expect on 2' of pipe. (I'm thinking that all the pressure drop is on the elbow and that the whole of the short pipe is at atmospheric pressure.)

What is downstream of the 2 foot pipe with the pressure sensor?  If it's just open to atmosphere, there's probably not enough pressure to measure.  Try obstructing the outlet with another valve, an orifice, a reducing fitting, etc.

Without more detailed information like diagrams and part numbers, we're just guessing here.
